# Pentax K1000 Hotshoe Broken

Tags: film, hotshoe-flash, pentax, hotshoe, pentax-k1000

I have a Pentax K1000 that I've been using for a while with a Neewer TT560 Flash Speedlite via the hotshoe. However, for whatever reason the flash has now stopped firing when the shutter closes.

I've tried two flashes on the camera, and neither fire, and have also put a flash on a different camera, which does fire it - so I know it's a problem with the hostshoe. Also, the battery is fine (the lightmeter still works) and that shouldn't affect the flash trigger anyway.

I had two questions:

1. Is there any way to fix the hotshoe?
2. Is there any way to trigger the flash without the hotshoe (I've heard people mention cable flash, but not sure how that would work with the mechanical Pentax K1000)?

I've attached a pic of the hotshoe as it seems to come up a little bit from the mount on the right hand side. Could this be the cause and how could I fix it?

[image]

Comment: From the picture it looks like the base plate could be sticking up far enough to prevent the pin on the flash from contacting correctly... can it be pushed down, or is it firmly stuck in that position?

Comment: @junkyardsparkle I thought that too, which is why I posted the pic :). I might take it off and try and make it flatter if possible. I'm also looking into getting a PC Sync Cord.

Comment: Is the metal frame a screwed-on part? You might find an intact one on a junk camera, or ... well, this might be one of the few cases where hammers and/or pump wrenches are helpful in maintaining photo gear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to fix the hotshot?

Hard to say if the hot shoe can be fixed, but it could certainly be replaced. You can find broken K1000's on eBay at very little cost (I saw one lot of four broken K1000's selling for around $30). On the other hand, you can find a working K1000 for just a little more than a broken one (maybe $50-$100), and it might be less hassle to just replace the camera.

> Is there any way to trigger the flash without the hotshoe (I've heard people mention cable flash, but not sure how that would work with the mechanical Pentax K1000)?

Yes, you can use a PC sync cord. If you look at the front of the camera, there's a connector on the body to the left of the lens. It may have a plastic plug in it that looks like a little black button -- just pull that out and you'll see the PC connector. A PC cord connects there and can be used to trigger any flash that has a PC connector. If you flash doesn't have such a connector, you can buy an [adapter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/767442-REG/Vello_HSA_PSU_Universal_Hot_Shoe_Adapter.html) that adds one.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking along the same lines as you on this. I've ordered a PC sync cord for my flash and will edit the answer to include pictures of how I rig that up when it comes. It was surprisingly hard to find any info on it for the Pentax K1000 online.

Comment: @JCollerton There's an extensive [K1000 manual here](http://www.pentax-manuals.com/markroberts/k1000_man.pdf).